# call shell script from another shell script in front end

Tags: shell, email, unix, mount, mailx

i created one script `space.sh` on one server and this script do ssh on other servers and check mount point. if password of any server is not working or expired it will simply print out server name or ip and will ask for password.

i want output on my mail. So for this i created one more script `mail.sh`. and simply called `sh space.sh >> test.txt` and with mailx getting this on my mail.

And here problem comes. while running mail.sh it is not asking for password because space.sh is now running in backend.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that your script space.sh is waiting for input, while the mailx program you call later is waiting for output. So you created a deadlock.

Scripts that are supposed to run non-interactively should not ask for user input.

I would advise to use public keys for the login and call ssh in a way it does not wait for input, i.e. does not use passwords, for example like this:

```
ssh -o "PubkeyAuthentication=yes" -o "PasswordAuthentication=no" hostname
```

If the login is not possible because of missing keys, this does not try PasswordAuthentication, but returns with an error: "Permission denied (publickey,password)."